# What is the possible title for this code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

```
unsigned int temp1=1;
unsigned char *temp2=(unsigned char*)&temp1;
if(!*temp2)
{
}
```

Can some explain what is the purpose of this code? I know how it's syntax is working but just like other codes of factorial, even number, String length, etc what's the title of this code?

Comment: It checks for [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Answer (score 1):

temp1 is an integer, so in this case it is two bytes. By setting temp1 to 1, temp1 has a byte which contains 0X01 and one which contains 0X00. The unsigned character pointer temp2 is set to point at the address of temp1. However, an unsigned char is only one byte, so when the if statement evaluates the value of temp2, it is only evaluating the value of the first byte in memory. Some systems store the low order byte of an integer in the lower memory address, and others store high low order byte in the lower memory address. This code determines which way the current system is formatting integer values.